# Android ProgressDialog Won't be dismiss after Paytm Transation on success

Tags: android, webview, progressdialog, paytm

when the paytm WebView calls "back to Activity" return. what should be the Approach to handle waiting for transation Complete.

My progress Dialog opened before Paytm Screen open but When returned from paytm screen to activity progress dialog not dismissing..

please any help or idea about this issue....

```
  1.OnSuccess of transaction i opened paytmcheckout() method 
  in this method i want to Dismiss or cancel the progressbarDialog.

  But it is not dismiss here.

    public void paytmCheckout(){
     if(_progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                _progressDialog.hide();
                _progressDialog.dismiss();
         }
    }

 2. progressDialog Declared globally
            ProgressDialog _progressDialog;

      onButtonClick()
             calls  openpaytm  Method


 My OpenPaytm method::
     private void openPaytm() {

        int price;
        if (discount != 0) {
        price = modalPlan.getInrPrice() - discount;
        } else {
            price = modalPlan.getInrPrice();
        }
 //Here`
 //my progressDialog is opened here successfully
//
    if(_progressDialog==null){
        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    final ProgressDialog _progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
            getActivity(),
            "Transation",
            "Progress....",
            true,
            true
    );
    }

    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(1000);
    Service = PaytmPGService.getStagingService(); //for production  environment
    PaytmMerchant Merchant = new    PaytmMerchant("https://app.mobikyte.com/paytm/generateChecksum.php", "https://app.mobikyte.com/paytm/verifyChecksum.php");

    HashMap<String, String> paramMap = new HashMap<>();
    paramMap.put("REQUEST_TYPE", "DEFAULT");
    paramMap.put("ORDER_ID", "" + modalAddCampign.getOrderId());
    paramMap.put("MID", "Audian53591216301431");
    paramMap.put("CUST_ID", modalLogin.getClientid());
    paramMap.put("CHANNEL_ID", "WAP");
    paramMap.put("INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID", "Retail");
    paramMap.put("WEBSITE", "AudianzN");
    paramMap.put("TXN_AMOUNT", "" + price);
    paramMap.put("THEME", "merchant");

    String par = paramMap.toString();
    Log.e("TESTING:", "Paytm Params" + par);
    PaytmOrder Order = new PaytmOrder(paramMap);
    Service.initialize(Order, Merchant, null);
    Service.startPaymentTransaction(getActivity(), false, false, new  PaytmPaymentTransactionCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onTransactionSuccess(Bundle bundle) {
            Log.d("TEST", "Bundle = =" + bundle);

              paytmCheckout();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTransactionFailure(String s, Bundle bundle) {
            Log.e("Error", "someErrorOccurred :" + s);

 //Not dismissing here also

            _progressDialog.dismiss();
    //             _progressDialog.cancel();
        }

        @Override
        public void networkNotAvailable() {
            Log.e("Error", "NetworkErrorOccurred :");
        }

        @Override
        public void clientAuthenticationFailed(String s) {
            Log.e("Error", "clientAuthenticationFailed :" + s);
        }

        @Override
        public void someUIErrorOccurred(String s) {
            Log.e("Error", "someUIErrorOccurred :" + s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onErrorLoadingWebPage(int i, String s, String s1) {
            Log.e("Error", "onErrorLoadingWebPage :" + s1);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: comment out `_progressDialog.cancel();`

Comment: call `_progressDialog` as global /public

Comment: i cross checked my code i declared progress dialog globally & try only dismiss also and both hide and cancel also.    when  paytm calls in background "back to activity" than debugger come to the _progressDialog.dismiss(). on this line debugger reach to the paytm webview.class in  Exception catch() block.